# Error Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd' in Visual Studio 2019 Preview

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, windows-10-iot-core, visual-studio-2019

I am just trying to load a sample windows IoT Core HelloWorld application in Visual Studio 2019 Preview. The application is getting built successfully in Visual Studio 2017, however, it is throwing an error as "Error Cannot resolve Assembly or Windows Metadata file 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd'   HelloWorld" in Visual Studio 2019.

[image]

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I just found what we need to do. You just need to follow the steps mentioned below to get rid of the error in Visual Studio 2019, I am not sure why the application was working fine in Visual Studio 2017 though.

1. Right click on the project and click on properties
2. Select the target version in the Application menu under Targetting section, you will get a warning as below.
   [image]
3. Once you are selected a target, your selection may look like this
   [image]
4. Clean and rebuild your solution
5. If you are still getting the error, close visual studio 2019 and reopen the project.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Sibeesh, have you installed the version 15063 of Windows 10 SDK on your development machine?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I just checked in my programs, I have 17763 installed in my machine.

Comment: Hi Sibeesh, so that's why you can target 17763 instead of 15063 in HelloWorld sample if you use [this one](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-iotcore-samples/blob/develop/Samples/HelloWorld/CS/HelloWorld.csproj#L14).

Comment: You must have installed the appropriate build of the SDK in order to target that version. Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/updates-and-versions/choose-a-uwp-version).